# Number of arguments in constrained optimization

Tags: calculus

Let us assume that we have the following optimization problem:
$$
\max_{x,y,z}f\left(x,y,z\right)
$$
subject to:
$$
x+y+z=4
$$
In the above, the constraint holds with equality. Is it true to say
that we only need to maximize over two arguments, as the third one
is pinned down by the constraint? In other words, is it sufficient
to choose an optimal $x^{*}$, $y^{*}$ and get $z^{*}$ from the
constraint simply?